# Maven test fails if parent test class is in depenedncy

Tags: maven-3

I have 2 maven modules and tests as following:

```
Module1 
`src/test/java/Parent` 

Module2 
`src/test/java/Test  // Test extends Parent`
```

Module1 has rumtime dependency on Module1

When I run mvn test, I get below error:

> org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
>   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
>   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
>   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
>   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Parent

Any idea what I may be doing correct?
Compilation in eclipse succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Maven unit tests are limited by module and will not be propagated which means you can't use them in other module. Unfortunately Eclipse does this separation not 100% correct as you already realized.

You can if you need create a so [called `test-jar` which contains](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) the files from `src/test/` which gives you the possibility to reuse those classes from an other module. This mean you need to add the following to your `Module1`:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

In you other module you need to add the dependency to this separately created artifact by using this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```